# Creating a facebook icon in CSS

Tags: html, css, graphics

I am trying to create a Facebook icon using CSS. Using some shape-making-tutorials from internet I was able to design a facebook icon as below:

[image]

The created shape is not right. I am trying to get a more polished result like:

[image]

I tried modifying the CSS but I was unable to do it properly. The HTML is used is in the following:

```css
#fb-icon {
  background: blue;
  text-indent: -999em;
  width: 120px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 15px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#fb-icon::before {
  content: "/20";
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  width: 40px;
  height: 90px;
  bottom: -30px;
  right: -37px;
  border: 20px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 40px;
}
#fb-icon::after {
  content: "/20";
  position: absolute;
  width: 55px;
  top: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #eee;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="fb-icon">

</div>
```

I want to know where's the problem in the Shape's CSS code. Kindly guide me.

Comment: Did you found any solution here?

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pbv7t3wm/1/)

```
<p class="logo">Facebook</p>


.logo {
    background: #4661b0; /* make it "Facebook blue" */
    text-indent: -999em; /* Back the actual text in the paragraph tag out of the element */
    width: 100px; /* Make it nice and big */
    height: 110px; /* The tag is 10px larger because of how we're handling the borders below */
    border-radius: 3px; /* for that oh so important modern look */
    position: relative; /* so we can position our other elements absolutely */
    overflow: hidden; /* so we can hide any overflow those elements will have */
    border: 15px solid #4661b0; /* so we can make it look like the F is not butting up against the right side of the box */
    border-bottom: 0; /* removing the border here though, because the F does touch the bottom of the box */
}

.logo:before {
    content: "/20"; /* Psuedo elements need something for content, this means a blank space */
    position: absolute; /* So we can position it exactly where we want it */
    background: #4661b0; /* make the box the same Facebook blue */
    width: 40px; /* setup the right width, which actually extends the box outside of the containing element (along with our positioning below) */
    height: 90px; /* this also extends the trunk outside of the main box */
    bottom: -30px; /* as mentioned above, we pull the box we're using to create the trunk of the F down to hide some of it, because it will have rounded corners on all sides */
    right: -37px; /* similar to what we're doing with bottom above */
    border: 20px solid white; /* make the remaining visible border white and thick enough to look right */
    border-radius: 25px; /* now give the top right visible corner the necessary curve */
}

.logo:after {
    content: "/20"; /* again, pseudo elements need content to be visible */
    position: absolute;  /* and we're going to want to position absolutely */
    width: 55px;  /* the desired width of the box to make the bar long enough */
    top: 50px;  /* set it in the proper location */
    height: 20px;  /* make it thick enough */
    background: white;  /* and the right color */
    right: 5px;  /* then back it up from the edge of the containing block a bit */
}
```

[Source](https://clicknathan.com/web-design/html-css-only-facebook-icon/)

Answer (score 0):

try this..

change `border-radius 40px;` to `border-radius: 25px;` to before element and add this css `border-bottom-left-radius: 0;`.. to same element

Answer (score 0):

Check out this.. Just change the some value in `:after` and `:before`. And `width` of the box

```css
#fb-icon {
  background: blue;
 text-indent: -999em;
  width: 100px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 12px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#fb-icon::before {
content: "/20";
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  width:29px;
  height: 90px;
  bottom: -30px;
  right: -25px;
  border: 20px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 28px;
}
#fb-icon::after {
 content: "/20";
  position: absolute;
  width: 56px;
  top: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #eee;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="fb-icon">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your css needs few changes , just change the `width` for `#fb-icon`, `border-radius` for `#fb-icon::before` and `right` for `#fb-icon::after` , check the changed css

```
#fb-icon {
  background: blue;
 text-indent: -999em;
  width: 100px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 15px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#fb-icon::before {
content: "/20";
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  width:40px;
  height: 90px;
  bottom: -30px;
  right: -37px;
  border: 20px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
#fb-icon::after {
 content: "/20";
  position: absolute;
  width: 55px;
  top: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #eee;
  right: 2px;
}
```

check out this link http://jsbin.com/weyebeg/edit?html,css,output